# Can you customise a post on Facebook Timeline?

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-timeline

As far as I understand, an App can post into a User's Timeline.

My question is, how much can you customase/style this post?
I believe you can, at least, add a custom image and links. Can you also add HTML elements and CSS?

---

for example, nikeplus and RunKeeper seem to add some basic styling:

http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yu/r/60YqMBkteVy.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**
No you can't.

**Longer answer with more details**
What you're looking for is called an *Open Graph Action*, it's not the usual Facebook status update. What you see in the screenshot linked by you, is an aggregation of all Open Graph Actions of a specific type.

You can not customize the layout of this aggregation. You can just select one of the 6 basic layouts and configure how the actions should be aggregated, sorted and/or filtered.

You can setup your own actions by going to the [Facebook Developer Center](https://developers.facebook.com/apps), select one of your FB Apps, set a namespace in the basic settings (if not already done) and then got to "Open Graph". Once you've set up your own actions you can create your aggregations.

**Here are a few links to get you started:**

- [How-To: Defining an Aggregation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/defining-an-aggregation/#layout)
- [Open Graph Technical Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/)
- [Open Graph Concepts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/opengraph/)

[image: Open Graph Actions Aggregation]